# Get all the tweets of the followers

Tags: haskell

```
urldata2 :: String
urldata2 = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="

allTweets :: [String] -> IO (Either String [Tweets])
allTweets listusers = do
    getWith authenticate (urldata2++(DL.head listusers) ) >>= \body1 -> getBody1 body1
```

this is the `allTweets` function i tried

getBody1 takes my response and `IO (Either String [Tweets])`

i want to get the tweets of all the users in the list, but i managed for only head user. 
how can i get for all users in the list?

Comment: Have you looked at `mapM`?

Comment: yes i managed to get it. thank u :)

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
allTweets1 listusers =
    mapM (\listu -> (getWith authenticate (urldata2++(listu) ) >>= \body1 -> getBody1 body1)  ) listusers
```

I was able to solve my problem using mapM as Thomas suggested.
I was facing the problem for map cause `(DL.map) :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`
it expects it to be in same container. 
But for `mapM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)` we can give it out in any container like format

Comment: Note that you don't need the `do` keyword here; `do a == a`. Also, I think `mapM` is effectively just retained for backwards compatibility, as it is just `traverse` specialized to monads rather than all applicative functors.

Comment: @chepner it's certainly not useful anywhere `traverse` isn't, but I think `mapM` is occasionally more descriptive than `traverse`. For instance `traverse print someValues` doesn't feel as obvious to me as `mapM print someValues`, though YMMV there.

Comment: @AdamSmith FWIW, my mileage does vary: I really like "traverse" as a name. I think it captures "walk across a structure, performing an action/computation/effect/what-have-you at each step" quite well. It is also evokes a sense of direction, which is one of the key things about `Traversable` (as opposed to, say, `Functor`).